# Concatention of string with boolean in java

Tags: java, string, concatenation

Can somebody please explain why does 5th line of code prints only false instead of 'Hello all false'.
Thanks

```
    class Hello {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           final String s1 = "Hello";
           final String s2 = "hello all" + s1.length();
           System.out.println("Hello all" + s1==s2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: first doing `"Hello all" + s1`, second `==` operation

Comment: Didn't someone just ask this question a few minutes ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java evaluates the final expression as `"(Hello all" + s1) ==s2`, rather than `"Hello all" + (s1==s2)`, as you probably intend.

Also, **never** compare `String`s with `==`, always use `s1.equals(s2)`. `==` checks to see if the two strings occupy the same location in memory.

Add brackets, and change to `.equals()` and it should work as intended.

EDIT

As Krystian suggested, it is worth pointing out the reason why the addition is performed after the equality check.

Every operator has a **precedence**, which represents the priority that operator has when there is ambiguity about the order of operations (i.e. when there are insufficient brackets to fully describe the order).

For example, when evaluating the expression `1 + 2 * 3`, that is grouped as `1 + (2 * 3)` (as it is in maths), because `*` has a higher precedence than `+`.

`==` is also an operator, and so also has a precedence. It has a lower precedence than `+`, so gets evaluated after `+`.

The following link explains more thoroughly, with a table of the precedences of all operators: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: It would be also nice to mention why `+` is evaluated before `==`. That's because operator `+` has higher precedence than operator `==` according to this table https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Yes worth explaining, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The fifth line of code prints the evaluation of the expression

```
"Hello all" + s1==s2
```

which is

```
("Hello all" + s1) == s2
```

which is

```
("Hello all" + "Hello") == "Hello all"
```

which is

```
false
```